# Biggest LEGO weapon

Tags: weapons, weapon-mass-destruction

What would be the most powerful ***real*** weapon if we could have an infinite quantity of LEGO pieces.
Assume current types/models/etc version of LEGO's.

I was thinking about some as simple as a gargantuan compact ball of LEGO's (Everest size?) and toss it from space (from Moon? Jupiter orbit?), but how can we re-direct/target it? (in the case we need attack our enemy). Note: This is not an option, because we are using *only* LEGOs (How can we put that thing into orbit/space?)

Maybe a catapult?

*If this is not the right place to ask, please let me know.*

Thanks.

[Related](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/127015/biggest-possible-battleship-that-can-be-built)

Comment: You don't have to make a lego ball the size of Everest. Typical american house size is enough to drop from orbit and destroy whole planet.

Comment: This isn't really the best place for such a question... have a read of the relevant bits of the [help centre](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for guidelines on what's a good fit here. That said, the answer to your question will likely involve something like a [relativistic kill vehicle](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/spacegunexotic.php#id--Relativistic_Weapons). If you really had "an inifinite quantity", you could just make a massive black hole that consumes everything instead...

Comment: I edited the original question.... Because... how we can (using ONLY LEGOS) put that thing into orbit?

Comment: You can't make an orbital launch system out of lego. No lego parts are energy dense enough. If you've got an infinite amount, just make a big hill next to the target and bury it. A million tonnes of ABS crushes just as well as a million tonnes of rock.

Comment: Welcome to the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange! Would you mind elaborating why you believe our site is suitable for LEGO weaponry? It might help us point you in the right direction and prevent your question being closed due to being off-topic.

Comment: @A Lambent Eye: Because the site says "building" (we want to build something). But if not, no problem. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Seems on topic to me. As Joe Blogg's answer points out, the end result is literally the building of worlds... all of them....

Answer (score 10):

***Infinity, you say??!?***

As long as you don’t mind collateral damage (and the use of the phrase ‘most powerful’ suggests you don’t), then the answer is simple:

*Brick holes*

Ok, that pun was awful, but the point is solid. Get enough lego bricks together and gravity will cause them to compress. First the bricks will simply deform, acting like a liquid and yielding heat. A lot of heat. You’ll start off with a ball of bricks, then a molten ball of plastic, then nuclear fusion will kick off in the carbon rich core of this molten-model and you’ll end up with a star. Made of lego.

Eventually (once you’ve poured in a couple of suns’ weight of knobs... yes, that is technical terminology) you’ll overcome electron degeneracy pressure and the star will collapse as all of its component atoms smush together. This may yield unexpected effects, such as blowing off the outer layers of carbon/oxygen plasma in a stud-based supernova. Pour in enough bricks and you overcome neutron degeneracy pressure and the star collapses into a black hole. The accretion disk of this black hole will be a glowing band of high impact plastic, heated to absurd degrees by the deformation of the once lovable toys under gravity.

Now, at this point the use of the word ‘infinite’ comes back to bite you. If we keep adding bricks this black hole will continue to grow. It will consume everything as you continue adding bricks, and over billions of years it will even start to deform space across the universe itself, undoing the work of the Big Bang and dragging all of existence into your increasingly absurd build.

Eventually everything will be part of this one black hole. At this point it’s entirely unclear what might happen, but I like to think that from this singularity of bricks a second Big Bang will occur, spawning a whole new universe.

And I guess you could say it would be made of Lego.

Comment: Thanks, that is a clever solution. But, what if we _just_ want to destroy a big and powerful enemy (and not die trying).

Comment: @JuanCa: Oh, in that case I’m afraid I can’t help you. I only use lego for models of less than ten thousand pieces or events of cosmological significance.

Comment: @JuanCa In that case you should stop adding lego bricks when you got enough for a supernova. It should obliterate any life as we know it within a couple light-years.

Comment: Lol, this is the exact answer I was thinking.  Using "Infinite" is a very dangerous constraint on WB.

Comment: Yes... maybe I had to change to "extremely big amount of LEGOs"

Comment: I am reminded of this, in which we had Moles instead of Legos. A mole of moles, that is...: https://what-if.xkcd.com/4/

Comment: @CaM Randall Munroe is my muse.